# Android Intent Filters - blank mimeType for proprietary file type

Tags: android, android-intent, android-manifest

I use an Intent Filter to associate my app with my proprietary file type, so the user can tap the file and open it in my app. Until recently I've been using one based on the file name:

```
<action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
<category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
<category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
<data android:mimeType="*/*" />
<data android:scheme="file" />
<data android:scheme="content" />
<data android:host="*" />
<data android:pathPattern=".*\\.rhr" />
```

(plus other variations of pathPattern to allow for folders)

It seems that since Android 7, apps are not able to share File URLs [Official docs](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/nougat/android-7.0-changes.html#sharing-files). No problem, we can just use a Mime Type:

```
<action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
<category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
<category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
<data android:scheme="file" />
<data android:scheme="content" />
<data android:mimeType="[???]" />
```

Except that some apps don't send a mime type. For example, the Samsung My Files app sends an empty string as the mime type.

I could resort to using "*/*", but that's a sure way to annoy people. Are there any other options?

Comment: "Are there any other options?" -- don't support `ACTION_VIEW`. At best, custom MIME types can work when dealing with URLs pointing to Web servers, if the Web server is configured to use that MIME type for your content. For pretty much anything else, clients will not know anything about your MIME type. That's not unique to Android. Samsung My Files is broken if it uses a blank MIME type, but there isn't a lot we can do about that.

Comment: So if I'm to support my file type including from apps like Samsung My Files then it sounds like I have to go the "\*/\*" route. Yuk!

Comment: Technically, `""` does not match `"*/*"` (no slash), so I'm not even sure that will work. Perhaps the `Intent` resolution process has special support for `*/*` that ignores the actual value for the MIME type.

Comment: It does appear to work, so I guess something like that must be going on. The empty mimeType from My Files is only for my custom file type, so I guess the mimeTypes for PDF etc must be coming from somewhere else.

Comment: Android has `MimeTypeMap` which knows how to convert between file extensions and MIME types for a hundred or so common file types. Samsung could be using that or something like it. Unfortunately, Android has never had a way to add entries to `MimeTypeMap`.

Answer (score 1):

The sad answer is that is no good solution but to use `*/*` and no file extension filtering.

When Samsung's file manager tries opening a file whose mime type they don't recognize, they default to passing `""` (an empty string), which is impossible to filter for  - setting an empty mime type in the intent filter creates a malformed APK that your device will refuse to install, so the only way to catch it is by using `*/*`.

They probably should have defaulted to `application/octet-stream`, but that's not going to happen anytime soon - unless you work for Samsung, in which case, go change it :)

`*/*` could have been tolerable if you only included files ending in your custom extension (`*.rhr`) - however, that's not possible, either, because ever since migrating to `content://` URIs, the file name is hidden from the receiving application (the URI path is commonly just an opaque integer).